# Pandas: Write into Dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to write into a Pandas DataFrame.  I have 4 lists, which I could convert into series if necessary, that I need in this DataFrame.

```
l1
l2
l3
l4
```

Using this:

```
df1 = DataFrame(l1)
df2 = DataFrame(l2)
df3 = DataFrame(l3)
df4 = DataFrame(l4)
```

I am able to create 4 separate DataFrames.  However, I want 1 DataFrame with these 4 lists as the columns, without losing the order of the lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick, just give a list of lists to the dataframe costructor

```
DataFrame([l1, l2, l3, l4]).T
```

You need to trasnalte the dataframe as it will put your data in the wrong direction (by row instead that by column). If you need meaningful names you can set the columns name afterward

Answer (score 2):

```
In [3]: l1 = range(5)

In [4]: l2 = range(5,10)

In [5]: l3 = range(10,15)

In [6]: l4 = range(15,20)

In [10]: pd.DataFrame([l1,l2,l3,l4],index=['l1','l2','l3','l4']).T
Out[10]: 
   l1  l2  l3  l4
0   0   5  10  15
1   1   6  11  16
2   2   7  12  17
3   3   8  13  18
4   4   9  14  19
```

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method using a dict:

```
In [1]: pd.DataFrame({'l1':l1, 'l2':l2, 'l3':l3, 'l4':l4})
Out[1]:
   l1  l2  l3  l4
0   0   5  10  15
1   1   6  11  16
2   2   7  12  17
3   3   8  13  18
4   4   9  14  19
```

Comment: technically you should specify the columns as well, as they are only in order because of the sorting of the keys!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I missed that the OP wants the order maintained.  Good to know!